# Create PDF of the datastored in Javascript of HTML file

Tags: php, css, pdf

I want to create pdf files of pie charts and graphs which are dynamically generated using javascript.
I am using pdfdom for creating the pdf files using php.

But the Problem is that pdfdom is unable to create pdf of the data stored in the javascript here is the sample of my HTML file..

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table, 
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

  // Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', 3],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 1], 
    ['Zucchini', 1],
    ['Pepperoni', 2]
  ]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                 'width':400,
                 'height':300};

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any other way to do it please help..its urgent..!!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:have you tried pchart http://pchart.sourceforge.net/ ? You can use jquery to generate the chart. You can access the script via AJAX(generating the image and making the PDF) and and the response of that script you can get the link of the PDF file.